# function Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn JQuery and I got this error. `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`
I'm trying to point the selector without using any events function.

```
        let a = $("td:contains('"+ word +"')") = function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').hide();
            $(this).closest('tr').wrap('<hidden>');
            state = true;
        }         
        a();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is expected output

Comment: *"point the selector without using any events function"* - What does that even mean?  If your goal is for `a` to be a function, what is the intent of having `$("td:contains('"+ word +"')")` there?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0):

The error likely lies in this part:

```
$("...")=function(){...}
```

[`$("...")` already returns an object](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), so you can't assign a `function()` to it.

From your code, I *guess* what you want may be this:

```js
let a=(function(){...}).bind($("..."));

a();
```